# 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I followed this [link](http://npmasters.com/2012/11/25/Symfony2-Rest-FOSRestBundle.html) 
when I run this command to see if the Get method works very well I have this error displayed in my terminal **ERROR 415: Unsupported Media Type.**

I'm going to see my source code :

**1-  First I set my config file :**

> #app/config/config.yml
>       sensio_framework_extra:
>           view:
>               annotations: false
>
> fos_rest:
>
> ```
> param_fetcher_listener: true
> body_listener: true
> format_listener: true
> view:
>     view_response_listener: 'force'
> ```

**2- After i just fix my routing file :**

> #app/config/routing.yml
>
> ```
> minn_ads_api:
>     resource: "@MinnAdsAPIBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
>     type: rest
> ```

**3- I have also set the routing file in my **AdsAPIBundle*** :*

> ```
> #AdsAPIBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
> brend:
>     type: rest
>     resource: Minn\AdsAPIBundle\Controller\BrendController
> ```

**4- Under my AdsAPIBundle I just insert the function :**

```
#src/BundleApi/Controller/BrendController.php
    /**
     * @Rest\View
     * @Rest\Get("/api/brend/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
     */
    public function getAction($id) {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->
                getManager()->
                getRepository("MinnAdsBundle:Brend");
        $brend = $repo->find($id);

        return array('brend' => $brend);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you need to add a default format:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

Comment: The entity  is  found, and  we return a 200 OK !!

> **HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

Comment: What Content-Type do you see in the response header? Do you support this one on your client side?